# Establish Connection between AzureEventHub & AzureKubernetes

Tags: azure, networking, azure-aks, azure-eventhub

I have AzureEventHub setup and its opened for a selected network, which means, only the IPs that are whitelisted can be accessible.

On the other end, i have AzureKubernetesService configured to read messages from AzureEventHub. I get connection error saying broker not available, because the IPs of kubernetes is not whitelisted in eventhub.

Question is : Where would i get the IPs of AKS that can be configured in my AzureEventHub ?

What is already tried : In Overview of AKS Cluster, we have certain IPs as below.

```
Pod CIDR

Service CIDR

DNS service IP

Docker bridge CIDR
```

Adding the above isn't working !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) in Azure Event Grid. This can be done either through **CLI** or **Powershell**.

There is a set of commands you need to perform to complete the task:

1. Enable the Event Grid resource provider
2. Create an AKS cluster using the `az aks create` command
3. Create a namespace and event hub using `az eventhubs namespace create` and `az eventhubs eventhub create`

Refer the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quickstart-event-grid?tabs=azure-cli) to implement by using the given examples